# Search for new added divs on a webpage

Tags: python, html, selenium-chromedriver

I have to search for only newly added divs into a webpage; these divs are added in real time. Imagine Amazon.com where products are placed into `<div>` tags.

What I need to do is click on the latest product (-->div) added in the webpage and click it. The page does not need to be refreshed, the new item appears on the page automatically. The attributes I know are added to the new div added are "class" and "name". I need something that observes/listens for changes on the webpage, and when a new div is added, clicks it. Is it clear what I want to accomplish?

I am free to use any programming languages or frameworks.

Comment: Please share some of your code to make it specific.

Comment: _Can you please help me?_ Yes we can, but you'll have to specify your problem first.

Comment: Imagine Amazon.com where products are placed into <divs>. What I need to do is to click on the latest product (-->div) added in the webpage and click it. The page does not require to be refreshed, the new item appears automaticly on the page. The attributes I know of the new div added are "class" and "name". I need something that is observing/listening for changes on the webpage and when a new div is being added to click it. Is it clear what I want to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

You can collect div elements as a object list. After new div's adding you can collect them again as a new object list and you will be able to compare them. For example. :

```
firstlyListedDivs = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("classnameOfYourElements")
```

After new divs are appeared,

```
afterDivsAddedToListedDivs = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("classnameOfYourElements")
```